# Both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other - even after following same Generic definition

Tags: java, caching, concurrency

I am trying to extend ConcurrentHashMap (just for FUN) and noticing following compilation error stating ...

> Both methods have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

```
public class SimpleCacheImpl2<K, V> extends ConcurrentHashMap<K,SoftReference<V>> {

public void put(K key, V data){ // Compilation error at this line 
    SoftReference<V> softData = new SoftReference<V>(data);
    super.put(key, softData);
}

public V get(K key){ // Compilation error at this line
    SoftReference<V> softData =  super.get(key);
    return softData == null ? null : softData.get() ;
}
```

}

My intention is to use SoftReference for the data. Any suggestions to create a Simple Cache, please?

**EDIT 1:**

After suggestions from Boris & Pshemo, I am going ahead with the following implementation to tweak and introduce my feature. Just showing the basic ones and will extend more custom feature similarly.

```
public class SimpleCacheImpl2<K, V> extends ConcurrentHashMap<K,SoftReference<V>> {

@Override
public SoftReference<V> put(K key, SoftReference<V> data){
    return super.put(key, data);
}

@Override
public SoftReference<V> get(Object key){ 
    return super.get(key);
}

public V putItem(K key, V data){
    SoftReference<V> softData = put(key,new SoftReference<>(data));
    return softData.get();
}

public V getItem(K key){
    SoftReference<V> softData = get(key);
    return softData != null ? softData.get() : null;
}
```

}

Comment: You’ve bumped into type erasure, your methods clash with those declared in the parent class but only after genetics are erased. You’re going to need to use the **exact same** signatures to override parent class methods. (Yes, I know, return type covarince etc, but let’s not complicate matters). Specifically there is already a `put` method declared in the parent that is `K, SoftReference<V>`, and similar for `get`.

Comment: A more pertinent is, perhaps, _why `extends ConcurrentHashMap` at all_? This is a classic case where you should prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: Is `extends ConcurrentHashMap` a *must*? Are you planning to let users use your class as representation of `ConcurrentHashMap` for instance when we have `void foo(ConcurrentHashMap<...> map)` should user be able to pass `SimpleCacheImpl2` to it like `foo(new SimpleCacheImpl2() );`?

Comment: Anyway by `extends ConcurrentHashMap<K,SoftReference<V>>` your class also inherits `public V put(K key, SoftReference<V> value)` method which you may not want in your class API (BTW it is that method which is causing first compilation error). This is another reason to not extend it but use composition, even like `class YourClass implements Map<K,V>{ private ConcurrentHashMap<K,SoftReference<V>> data = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); @override public V put(K key, V value) { data.put(key, new SoftReference<>(value);} ...}`

Comment: Thank you all for replying and showing me some ideas. Yes, my initial attempt to use Composition as it is the standard pattern, however, I am hoping for some tweaking features and create a Custome ConcurrentHashMap by extending the provided one. Now, I have corrected the overriding implementation of put and get method to comply with the generic signature. Also, introduced a custom getItem and putItem method to tweak my custom features. I hope, this will work. Otherwise, I will proceed with Composition for sure :)